# Concatenate class @Path annotation to method @Path annotation when using colon

Tags: java, path, annotations, jersey, jax-rs

I ran into a problem when trying to port our old ERX rest routes to Jerey/JAX-RX.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
@Path("/v0/user")
@Controller
public class UserRouteController {

    @GET
    public Response getAllUsers(){
    ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    public Response getUserWithName(@PathParam("name") String name){
    ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path(":accessibleWithNoRestriction")
    public Response getUsersAccessibleWithNoRestriction(){
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path(":withAdminStatus")
    public Response getUsersWithAdminStatus(){
        ...
    }
```

However, Jersey does not want to match my http request.

```
blahblah.com/v0/user:accessibleWithNoRestriction
```

I get a No Method Allowed response.

Comment: Few things you can provide that might be useful like, web.xml, spring-bean.xml, actual output that you get on console.

Comment: wouldn't it be `blahblah.com/v0/user:accessibleWithNoRestriction`? (note the missing `/v0`)

Comment: Hi, i edited the post to add the v0 (typo in post). It all works when instead of the colon I put a '/' in both the request and method Path. What I think is that Jersey is trying to match user:accessibleWithNoRestriction to a path. Not breaking it down to user at class level and then :accessibleWithNoRestriction at method level. If I changed the Path at method level to /accessibleWithNoRestriction and request to blahblah.com/v0/user/accessibleWithNoRestriction then it matches and works. I hope I explained this a little better this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post: [JAX-RS Application on the root context - how can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874188/jax-rs-application-on-the-root-context-how-can-it-be-done)

Try using this:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class PathingFilter implements Filter { 
    Pattern[] restPatterns = new Pattern[] {
        Pattern.compile("/v0/user:.*")
    };

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {

            String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getPathInfo();

            for (Pattern pattern : restPatterns) {
                if (pattern.matcher(path).matches()) {
                    String[] segments = path.split(":");
                    String newPath = segments[0] + "/" + segments[1];
                    newPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath() + "/" + newPath;
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(newPath).forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Then you'll have to change the @Path annotation in your method to "/accessibleWithNoRestriction"

What this would do is change the uri of your request before the matching happens.

Try that

Answer (score 3):

I normally don't include the leading/trailing `/`'s in my paths, so I'm pretty sure `@Path("rootLevel")` and `@Path("methodLevel")` actually maps to `rootLevel/methodLevel` *not* `rootLevelMethodLevel`.

So in your example, `@Path("/v0/user")` and `@Path(":withAdminStatus")` maps to `/v0/user/:withAdminStatus`. Try changing your paths to something like this:

```
@Path("v0")
@Controller
public class UserRouteController {
  @GET
  @Path("user")
  public Response getAllUsers(){
    //...
  }

  @GET
  @Path("user/{name}")
  public Response getUserWithName(@PathParam("name") String name){
    //...
  }

  @GET
  @Path("user:accessibleWithNoRestriction")
  public Response getUsersAccessibleWithNoRestriction(){
    //...
  }

  @GET
  @Path("user:withAdminStatus")
  public Response getUsersWithAdminStatus(){
    //...
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to pull something off with some kind of redirection. For example, with a [**Pre-matching Filter**](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e6461). I've never done anything like this, but the documentation suggests that "you can even modify request URI". With that in mind, you could replace any request with `:withAdminStatus` in the URI with `/:withAdminStatus` so that it can be matched with the correct resource.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct on your explanation and thats whats happening. However, we have multiple classes with the "v0" path where this is happening (the use of semicolons in the path), ie: v0/patient:withNoRequiredAccess etc

Comment: @Rosa updated the answer with a link describing pre-matching filters. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Thanx buddy! The pre-matching filter looks like a very clean solution. We are currently using an older version of Jersy and it is not supporte in 1.17. But if upgrading is the only solution then I guess we need to upgrade :) Thanks again!