# javax.ws.rs.Path how to intercept just the project root without compromising all the other paths

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-8, url-pattern, servlet-listeners

I have this `web.xml`, don't want a suffix for the `url-pattern` so I'm using a `/*` pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my `RestVersion.java` class that I want to manage the root requests:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/")
public class RestVersion implements IRestVersion{
    @EJB
    private VersionBean versionBean;
    
    @Override
    public VersionInfo version() {
        return versionBean.getVersion();
    }
}
```

Where `IRestVersion.java` is the following:

```
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Local
public interface IRestVersion {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public VersionInfo version();
}
```

The problem is that any other path is intercepted by this RestVersion class, like this:

- `http://localhost:8080/`    ---> it answers correctly with the RestVersion.version() json
- `http://localhost:8080/asd` ---> it is intercepted always by RestVersion but I would like to manage this on another class which will have a `@Path("/asd")` on top (but in this moment I cannot with this configuration)

How can I intercept just the project root without compromising all the other paths?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874188/jax-rs-application-on-the-root-context-how-can-it-be-done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@Path("/")` at class level. And in the other classes you want to manage, add their specific `@Path("/asd")`.

At the end is all a hierarchy, starting by `@ApplocationPath`, followed by `@Path` at class level and ending in `@Path` at method level.

With combinations of those you should be able to manage any case.

The `@GET`, if found in a method without `@Path`, will manage `GET` requests of the `@Path` of the class level annotation.

**Update:** Adding an example

So, avoiding interfaces for simplification (although I only use them if necessary), you should accomplish what you want with this 2 classes:

```java
@Path("/")
public class RestVersion {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0.0";
    }
}
```

and

```java
@Path("/asd")
public class ASDController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getAsd() {
        return "ASD";
    }
}
```

And to activate JAX-RS you can do it via `web.xml` or simply by adding this other class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRSActivator extends Application {
}
```

Comment: The problem, is that using `@Path("/")` all the others (like `@Path("/asd")`) are shadowed by the `@Path("/")`, maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Hi. I updated the response to add an example. Just tested it in a Wildfly server and `/` responds `1.0.0` and `/asd` responds `ASD`.

Comment: It seems to work... No shadowing... I tried even with my `web.xml` and without your `JaxRSActivator` and it's ok too. Maybe I was confused. Thank you very much, I'll make some other tests and I'll approve this answer soon.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You are most welcome :)