# Loading resources using Jersey and @ApplicationPath annotation

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to deploy a basic jersey restful service to Tomcat7 without web.xml:

```
 @WebServlet(loadOnStartup=1)
 @ApplicationPath("resources")
 @Path("/mypath/{name}")
 public class MyResource extends Application {

 @Override
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
     Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
     s.add(MyResource.class);
     return s;
 }

 @GET
 @Consumes("text/plain")
 @Produces("text/plain")
 public String getWelcome(@PathParam(value = "name") String name) {
     return "Welcome to jax-rs " + name;
 }
}
```

I'm presented with a 404 when trying to access: */myapplication/resources/mypath/sample*.

I can deploy a servlet using the `@WebServlet` annotation, so this has nothing to do with the loading of servlets without web.xml into Tomcat7.

From reading the documentation for Jersey, the runtime should scan for classes extending `Application` and execute `getClasses()`, loading all root resources.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9373081/1305344

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which version of Jersey are you using? Try splitting application and resource in two classes. Definitely remove `@WebServlet` annotation. I.e. have one class extending Application annotated with `@ApplicationPath` and another class annotated with `@Path`.

EDIT: Make sure that `jersey-servlet.jar` is included in your WAR file.

Comment: I'm using v1.14 of Jersey. I tried splitting out the `Application` from the root resource class... to no avail. Having done  that, I'm still trying to access the resource at the same URL.

Comment: Do you have jersey-servlet.jar in your war file?

Comment: That fixed it. I don't understand, how is the Jersey specific servlet from jersey-servlet being referenced and loading my resources?

Comment: Using the servlet3 ServletContainerInitializer mechanism - Jersey registers a custom ServletContainerInitializer through META-INF services. This gets called by the servlet container if `@ApplicationPath` or `@Path` annotated classes are found and registers the custom Jersey servlet automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So what is the custom Jersey servlet that's registered? Is that a servlet generated by Jersey after processing my root resource classes, provides, etc.?

Comment: It's `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` with the URL mapping derived from the `@ApplicationPath` annotation value.

Comment: What about additional configuration like <async-supported>true</async-supported> ? ... can i include them using annotation only?

Comment: @MartinMatula you should add the `jersey-servlet.jar` hint to the answer.

Comment: @MartinMatula when you say `jersey-servlet.jar` you mean `jersey-container-servlet-2.27.jar` and `jersey-container-servlet-core-2.27.jar`?