# Jersey setup without web.xml

Tags: maven, jersey, tomcat7

I'm attempting to set up a simple REST web application that uses [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net). In the documentation, it seems that I should be able to create my application without using a web.xml file. From [the site](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html):

> JAX-RS provides a deployment agnostic abstract class Application for declaring root resource and provider classes, and root resource and provider singleton instances. A Web service may extend this class to declare root resource and provider classes.

The example that follows shows this code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(HelloWorldResource.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

To me, this says that I can use an `Application` class to do all of my servlet setup. This seems to be the configuration that reads my resource class's annotations and sets up the correct URL handling mechanisms. Is that correct? I don't have to do any other setup?

---

I ask because I created the following and it didn't work (I get a 404 from `localhost:8080/{context}/test`):

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyTestApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(JerseyTestController.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Resource class:

```
@Path("/test")
public class JerseyTestController 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTestMsg() 
    {
        return "It works";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dumb. All I had to do was include the `jersey-servlet` jar, as prescribed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772438/557481).