# Spring Jersey: How to get rid of web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, maven-cargo

I am creating my application as ([link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html))

```
public class InventoryApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public InventoryApplication() {
        packages("com.org.my_services.inventory.services");
    }
}
```

I have blank `web.xml` that I want to get rid of

When I use cargo to deploy my war in tomcat `mvn cargo:run`, it fails

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Premature end of file.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/services/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1019)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1809)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1247)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/services/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/services/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1019)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1809)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1247)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Occurred at line 1 column 1
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Error getConfigured
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Context [/services] startup failed due to previous errors
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/inventory/integration/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat7x/webapps/host-manager
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/inventory/integration/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat7x/webapps/manager
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] May 03, 2014 3:16:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Server startup in 787 ms
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 7.x started on port [8080]
```

How can I tell my container to look for `InventoryApplication`?

Answer (score 0):

You need jersey-servlet on your classpath.

See:

- [Jersey setup without web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816561/jersey-setup-without-web-xml)
- [Loading resources using Jersey and @ApplicationPath annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768514/loading-resources-using-jersey-and-applicationpath-annotation/12772438#12772438)