# JAX-RS Application sub-class not registering

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jax-rs, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to develop a RESTful webapp using the Servlet 3.0 [Application](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class on Tomcat 7.0.34.0, but nothing seems to work. I've had no problem with previous apps using the Jersey ServletContainer approach and declaring all REST services in the web.xml.

My current Application sub-class:

```
package aaa;

@ApplicationPath("/test")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses ()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>> ();
        resources.add (aaa.TestResource.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

and the web service:

```
package aaa;

@Path("test")
public class TestResource
{
    public TestResource () {}

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getXml ()
    {
        return "TEST SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

When I try to deploy the app, Tomcat tells me the context has been reloaded:

```
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/WebApplication1] has started
Nov 10, 2013 7:06:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/WebApplication1] is completed
```

The web app itself is deployed (I can access its JSP pages) - however, the "test" resource remains unavailable. I've tried every possible URL and get only 404 in response. It seems ApplicationConfig is never even loaded.

A point of interest: following the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml), I've tried adding a small web.xml with no  and removing the @ApplicationPath. The result is a NullPointerException, which is exactly the behaviour I would expect in a Servlet 2.x environment (no class specified, so the ClassLoader crashes).

I'm at a loss here. Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong ?

PS: I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1, project is [Java Web -> Web Application -> Java EE 6 Web] with no extra library and no context/dependency injection.

Comment: I don't see a subclass. Show us the code of `SimpletestResource`.

Comment: @LutzHorn My apologies - I actually renamed SimpletestResource to TestResource in the middle of posting the question, and forgot to correct the code I posted. ApplicationConfig does in fact add TestResource properly - editing the question now to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` resource is defined in `TestResource` class, while the overriden `getClasses` method returns a set with only `SimpletestResource.class`. Although I don't know how does `SimpletestResource` look like, but AFAIK `@Path` is not inherited. So, I think you should put `TestResource.class` in that set.

Tried and tested on Tomcat 7.0.27 with NetBeans 7.4. Added the libraries: JAX-RS 2.0 and Jersey 2.0.

Comment: That's a mistake on my part: the code actually adds `TestResource` in `ApplicationConfig`. I've updated the question. Sorry for that.