# Created a restful webservice using tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, rest, tomcat, glassfish

I created a restful webservice using netbeans created a entity class from the database and restful web services from entity class using jpa but i used tomcat as my server now the post method below wont insert the following json into the database but when i use glassfish as my server it works. Do you think I am missing any dependencies ? How can I emulate the glassfish?

I am trying to insert

```
{
"acceptedGender":"both",
"price":123123.00,
"type":"apartment"
"vacantNum":13,
"hadID":4
}
```

I have the following dependencies:
javaee-api-7.0.jar
javax.ejb-api.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar

```
 @POST
 @Override
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 public void create(Students entity) {
    super.create(entity);
 }`
```

---

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "hatID")
private Integer hatID;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "type")
private String type;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "acceptedGender")
private String acceptedGender;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "vacantNum")
private int vacantNum;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields 
consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "price")
private BigDecimal price;
//    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "hatID")
//    private Collection<Reservation> reservationCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "hadID", referencedColumnName = "hadID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private HaDetails hadID;

public HaTypes(Integer hatID, String type, String acceptedGender, int 
vacantNum, BigDecimal price) {
    this.hatID = hatID;
    this.type = type;
    this.acceptedGender = acceptedGender;
    this.vacantNum = vacantNum;
    this.price = price;`
```

---

Or if you dont have a solution to my problem could you recommend any provider aside from aws(dont have the time to study the docker), openshift and jelastic that could deploy a glassfish restful webservice on cloud easily.

Comment: any error messages anywhere?

Comment: @Jan there arent any error messages its just it wont insert values in the database but when i use glassfish it inserts values into the database using the same code

Comment: did you check catalina.out? If it's not inserting into the DB, maybe your DB connection is not established - how to set this up properly would differ between glassfish and tomcat

Comment: @Jan i did check the catalina.out and the connection was established in the  netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish is an application server, therefore it supports JAX-RS out of the box. Tomcat is just a web container and you cannot deploy a JAX-RS app and have it work without wiring it by yourself (see this: [In which container do JAX-RS web services run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987513/in-which-container-do-jax-rs-web-services-run)).

If you want to run a Jersey server inside tomcat, you will need to configure it in your application's deployment descriptor.
You can see answers on the following posts if you need details:

- [How to use Jersey as JAX-RS implementation without web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729363/how-to-use-jersey-as-jax-rs-implementation-without-web-xml/29730471#29730471)
- [Create RESTful Web Service with JAX-RS and deploy it to tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442632/create-restful-web-service-with-jax-rs-and-deploy-it-to-tomcat)