# Jersey doesn't find Resources : 404 error

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am working on a simple RESTful Api using **Jersey 2.10** and running on **Tomcat 8**.

this is my **Application** class :

```
package com.manager.api.application;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath ("api")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application () {
        packages ("com.manager.api.resources");
    }   
}
```

My **Resources** package contains :

an interface :  **Resources.java**

```
package com.manager.api.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public interface Resources {

    @GET
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject getList ();

    @GET
    @Path ("value=/{id}")
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject get (String id);

    @POST
    @Path ("value=/{data}")
    @Consumes (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void post (JsonObject data);

    @PUT
    @Path ("value=/{data}")
    @Consumes (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void put (JsonObject data);

    @DELETE
    @Path ("value=/{id}")
    public void delete (String id);
}
```

An abstract class : **ResourcesImpl.java** which implements the Resources interface

```
package com.manager.api.resources;

public abstract class ResourcesImpl implements Resources {  
}
```

And finally a resource class which extends ResourcesImpl.java : **UserResources.java**

```
package com.manager.api.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.manager.api.dao.UserDao;

@Path ("value=/users")
public class UserResources extends ResourcesImpl {

    private UserDao user = new UserDao ();

    @GET
    @Path ("value=/test")
    @Produces (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String Test () {
        return "Test";
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObject getList () {
        return user.getList ();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonObject get (String id) {
        return user.get (id);
    }

    @Override
    public void post (JsonObject data) {
        user.post (data);
    }

    @Override
    public void put (JsonObject data) {
        user.put (data);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String id) {
        user.delete (id);
    }
}
```

and my **web.xml** contains only a `<display-name>` Tag :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>manager-api</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I run my project successfully but I get 2 problems :

***The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public JsonObject com.manager.api.resources.UserResources.get(java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.*** : Which I find strange since I put `@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and didn't put a `@Consumes` for this method.

Finally the big problem is the **404 error** I get when I type : **`http://localhost:8080/manager-api/api/users/test`** when  it should print `Test` as text.

Do you have any idea about what is the reason behind those 2 errors ? Thank you.

Comment: do you have a `<servlet-mapping>` or `<filter-mapping>` tag in your web.xml?

Comment: @Xinzz : Thank you for your answer. No I don't. it's said in the official doc : For simple deployments, no web.xml is necessary at all. Instead, an `@ApplicationPath` annotation can be used to annotate the custom Application subclass and define the base application URI for all JAX-RS resources configured in the application. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html

Comment: I know this is old, but your paths should be in the format @Path("/test") or @Path(value="/test"), not @Path("value=/test").

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your pom.xml has servlet 3.0 and not 2.0. Also try giving an absolute path instead of a relative one in your @ApplicationPath annotation (such as "/api"). Also maybe your package declaration is incorrect for the resourceconfig?

Refer to this if you have more troubles:
[How to set up JAX-RS Application using annotations only (no web.xml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually didn't use Maven. Is it mandatory ?

Comment: It's not required but I would highly recommend it. Check out https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html for a tutorial. I would generate a maven archetype of a sample Jersey project and go from there :)