# @QueryParam in JAX-RS 1.1 with Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5 doesn't receive value

Tags: jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I'm using the following code to create WebService without configuration in web.xml like described here: [How to set up JAX-RS Application using annotations only (no web.xml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml)

```
@ApplicationPath("/host")
@Path("/merge")
public class FormProvider extends Application {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getFormByKey(@QueryParam("key") String key) {

        Form form = DB.getFormByKey(key);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();
        String json = gson.toJson(form);

        return json;
    }
}
```

And using following URL to invoke WebService with parameters:

> http://localhost:9081/MyRestApplication/host/merge?key=xyz123

Webservice being invoked but property `key` remains empty, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

**Update**: 
*It began to work. I can't explain but I just removed jax-rs library, turned-off server and then turned-on and added library (same library) back and it began to work. Before it I tried to perform clean, build, nothing helped. If somebody will be able to explain what and why did it happen, I will accept it as answer. Thank you*.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a "key" parameter in your query. Change it to:

```
http://localhost:9081/MyRestApplication/host/merge?key=xyz123
```

Comment: Sorry, I checked with `key` and with `test` and in both cases it didn't work. Just copied here wrong code, will fix it.