# How to respond to queries in jax-rs

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've been doing this JAX-RS project and I have a question about queries. Let's say I want to add Users to my WEB application. I would create an entity from my database, then get information with DAO class and create controller for user. It should look something like this:

```
@Path("user")
public class UserController {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    return "GOT IT";
}
}
```

So, my question is when I start the server on localhost, how do I listen on .../user on my machine?

Comment: What do you mean by "listen"? The one component that does the listening is the actual server, on the specified port. The container forwards the request to the JAX-RS application, which forwards the request to the matching URI (among other matching parameters). Is there something not working for you that caused you to ask this question?

Comment: I guess he is asking how to register the JAX-RS bean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up JAX-RS Application using annotations only (no web.xml)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml)