# JAVA HTTP Status 500 - Authenticator.invoke() failed

Tags: java, rest, maven, web, sap-cloud-platform

In my Java app, I'm getting the following error for all Rest service calls like:

https://example.com/secselfservice/rest/ping

which returns: HTTP Status 500 - Authenticator.invoke() failed

**Log of the error:**

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Authenticator.invoke() failed at
 com.sap.core.jpaas.security.auth.service.lib.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:174)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
 at
 com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:168)
 at
 com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:94)
 at
 com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:38)
 at
 com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
 at
 org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
 at
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
 at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:807) Caused by:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method
 java.lang.String.length() of a null object loaded from local variable
 'name' at
 org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
 at
 org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
 at
 org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
 at
 org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:91)
 at
 org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:139)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:427) at
 org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.ChainedClassLoader.doLoadClass(ChainedClassLoader.java:174)
 at
 org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.ChainedClassLoader.loadClass(ChainedClassLoader.java:164)
 at
 org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWebappClassLoader.java:298)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:427) at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.servletSecurityAnnotationScan(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
 at
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
at
 com.sap.core.jpaas.security.auth.service.lib.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:170)
 ... 16 common frames omitted
```

**Here is the code of my web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>secselfservice</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.rest.SecSelfServApplication</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.rest.SecSelfServApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>user/Provider</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>com.sap.security.um.user.UserProvider</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>mail/SAPInternalNWCloudSession</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <description>All SAP HANA Cloud Platform users</description>
    <role-name>EVERYONE</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>Members of security team</description>
    <role-name>Approver</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>Read only access to admin view</description>
    <role-name>Viewer</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>Superadmin</description>
    <role-name>Tester</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Approver</role-name>
      <role-name>Viewer</role-name>
      <role-name>Tester</role-name>
      <role-name>EVERYONE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/CustomDataEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.Customization</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/MailTemplateEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.MailTemplates</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/QuestionEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.Questions</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/UsrVariantEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.UsrVariants</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ProjectEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.Projects</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ProjectRequestEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.ProjectRequests</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/UserEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.Users</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ResourcesEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.Resources</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ProjectAnswerObserverEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.observer.ProjectAnswerObserver</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ProjectDataObserverEJB</ejb-ref-name>
    <local>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.ejb.observer.ProjectDataObserver</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.rest.exception.WebServiceExceptionHandler</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**The code of the servlet SecSelfServApplication:**

```
/**
 * Application
 */
package com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.rest;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * JAX-RS Application
 */
public class SecSelfServApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(InitService.class);
        s.add(MailTemplateService.class);
        s.add(PingService.class);
        s.add(ProjectRequestService.class);
        s.add(ProjectService.class);
        s.add(QuestionService.class);
        s.add(ResourceService.class);
        s.add(UserService.class);
        s.add(UsrVariantService.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

**And for PingService.java:**

```
package com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.rest;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

//import com.qmino.miredot.annotations.ReturnType;
import com.sap.coe.securityselfservice.rest.bean.WebServiceException;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

/**
 * Rest Service - Ping
 * 
 * @author C5178621
 * @servicetag Ping
 */
@Path("/ping")
public class PingService {

  /**
   * Ping the rest service application and check if it is alive
   * 
   * @summary Test Application Alive
   * @return "pong" if application is up and running
   * @throws WebServiceException
   */
  @GET
  @Path("/")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @ApiOperation(value = "ping", notes = "ping", response = String.class)
  public Response ping() throws ServletException {
    return Response.ok().entity("pong").build();
  }
}
```

**Also the pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>-->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sap.it.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>hcp-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.sap.coe</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecSelfService</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>SAP DEVELOPER LICENSE AGREEMENT</name>
            <url>https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/developer-license-3.1.txt</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <url>git@github.example.corp:SRCOffice/SelfService_Backend.git</url>
            <connection>scm:git:git@github.example.corp:SRCOffice/SelfService_Backend.git</connection>
            <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.example.corp:SRCOffice/SelfService_Backend.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <war.name>secselfservice</war.name>
        <sap.cloud.application>secselfservice</sap.cloud.application>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Project plugin versions -->
        <version.eclipse-plugin>2.6</version.eclipse-plugin>
        <version.shade-plugin>2.2</version.shade-plugin>
    </properties>

    <!--Use Java EE6-->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>neo-javaee6-wp</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.it.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>hcp-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>secselfservice</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.eclipse-plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.shade-plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: If you still have this problem, did the jersey solution work for you as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, obviously classloading problems with no very useful hint from the eclipse (osgi) framework...
I've seen from time to time failing apps when they bring their own versions of libraries which collide with some libs that are already part of the provided platform.

Consider this [HCP maven blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/27/building-java-applications-with-maven/): there they reference one artifact and most imporantly they use `<scope>provided</scope>` to tell maven to NOT include the libs into your app's war file (as some jars are already provided by the platform).

My best bet is that at least org.eclipse.persistence is already provided by the platform (and maybe other libs you want as well).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error (my Q&A you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053408/is-it-possible-to-forward-a-request-from-a-webservlet-to-rest-helper-servlet-ja)) and found a solution in [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3548837) SAP discussion.

For me the error did no longer occur as soon as I added jersey manually and removed the `<servlet-class>` tag from the web.xml In the end the configuration within the web.xml wasn't necessary at all for my simple rest service (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml) answer).

So It seems that this is a Hana cloud platform specific problem.