# 404 returned while doing get on rest api with jaxrs+apache+eclipse, static index.html works just fine

Tags: rest, maven, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I created a jersey REST application (helloworld) with java+eclipse+tomcat 8.5+maven. The static index.html works fine when I run the project on server. But rest endpoint giving 404.

REST api Hello world class:-

```
@Path("/hello")
public class MyJerseyPage{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "Hello from Jersey";
    }
}
```

Rest config class:-

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RESTConfig extends Application {

}
```

POM.XML:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.nagendrahegde</groupId>
    <artifactId>therestproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>therestproject Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
           <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jsontoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsontoken</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>therestproject</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Web.xml:-

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Output:-

get on: http://localhost:8080/therestproject/api/hello -> 404 - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

The SAME SETUP used to work before, when pom.xml was having below versions of dependencies:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.44</version>
</dependency>
```

IT USED TO WORK! IT STARTED THROWING 404 WHEN I CHANGED POM.XML AND CHANGED THE JERSEY VERSION TO LATEST.
**I want to keep the latest jersey version since i have to do oauth2 on top of this. Please help.**

Answer (score 0):

This answer might point to a possible solution: add the `jersey-ri` dependency.

[How to set up JAX-RS Application using annotations only (no web.xml)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml)